# What is the best/ Easiest way (if any) to setup a subsonic server to stream music from a Drobo

Tags: networking, nas, music-streaming

My setup is essentially a modem router, connected to a gigabit router, which connects to a Drobo and a Computer. Everything works fine except I can't get the Subsonic music server to detect folders across the network on the Drobo. As a result I have to Drobo copy onto the local HDD which leaves me with 3 copies of my music folder and a little manual migration work when I add music. Obviously, I can remotely access the server and the music - just from the wrong location.

Is there a way to configure my network/ server such that Subsonic can read the folder sitting on the Drobo NAS?

Answer (score 0):

Mount the folders on the Drobo that have the music in them on the PC that is running Subsonic.  Those folders will then look to Subsonic like they are local.

Comment: For the record - I now have it appearing as both a drive and a folder.

Comment: Hold the phone - you may be right - it could be indexing, my error has gone. Stay tuned.